# IBM Navigator:ecm/widget/listView/ContentList with check boxes

Tags: dojo, filenet, ibm-content-navigator

I am having a big time difficulty in showing checkboxes against every row in the grid. I see there is a property showCheckBoxes in ContentList which I have set it to true. But still the checkboxes does not show up.

Here is code snippet.

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="dsResultsSearchPane" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" class="FormBox">
<div id="${id}_dsResultsSearch" data-dojo-attach-point="dsResultsSearch" data-dojo-type="ecm/widget/listView/ContentList" data-dojo-props="showCheckboxes:true">
</div>
</div>
```

Do I have to add an extra column while setting up the table structure (columns, headers etc.) or while loading the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using navigator version 3.0.8?
I think the ContentList check Box is available only at ver 3.0.8.

If you are using lower version of ICN, consider to implement your result by using Gridx instead, it is support row checkBox